# Android application stops unexcepetdly after importing and working in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

After I have moved to the Android Studio, Projects which are imported from Eclipse are force stopping when build and running on emulator and on device. When they are build and running from eclipse its working smoothly.

I have tested on emulator all versions above 2.3., All are showing same problem.
And also tested on Samsung galaxy ace, Galaxy Core, Xperia and some Microamx devices.

Is there any options to be set for the android studio?

Comment: Where is the error log ?

Comment: Are you using API level 21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop)

Comment: have you download latest version of AndroidStudio ? which is already given option to "Import non Android Studio project"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to go through this link and cross-verify what wrong you may be doing to import your eclipse project to android studio :

[MigratingToAndroidStudio](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html)

Answer (score 5):

First Of all Go through [this Documentation](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) and check the new [build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects)

and some useful blogs
***[Blog1](http://rexstjohn.com/exporting-android-project-eclipse-android-studio-0-4-0/)***  ***[Blog2](http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/06/07/migrating-your-android-app-from-eclipse-to-android-studio/)***

They might Help you

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse and Android Studio's Folder Structure is Different...
If you Export android project and Directly Import to Android Studio, That will not Working..

Comment: Wrong answer. Eclipse projects works in Android Studio directly.